HealthCheckServiceInstanceListSupplier is Deprecated how can i get ReactiveLoadBalancer.Factory<ServiceInstance> for new method
In my existing code we are using
public HealthCheckServiceInstanceListSupplier(ServiceInstanceListSupplier delegate,
                                                      LoadBalancerProperties.HealthCheck healthCheck,
                                                      BiFunction<ServiceInstance,String,reactor.core.publisher.Mono<Boolean>> aliveFunction)

How I have upgraded my spring cloud loadbalancer to 4.1.1
The above method is Deprecated in new version.
New method:
public HealthCheckServiceInstanceListSupplier(ServiceInstanceListSupplier delegate,
                                          ReactiveLoadBalancer.Factory<ServiceInstance> loadBalancerClientFactory,
                                          BiFunction<ServiceInstance,String,reactor.core.publisher.Mono<Boolean>> aliveFunction)

Now How can I get ReactiveLoadBalancer.Factory loadBalancerClientFactory
Thanks for the help

It should be a bean in the application context. Can you show how you are creating a HealthCheckServiceInstanceListSupplier?

@spencergibb added the code in question

context.getBean(LoadBalancerClientFactory.class);
